# @objc func expression resolves to an unused function

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm new to swift and trying to call a method when the user presses some hotkey shortcut.
I have the following [code](https://pastebin.com/pF8wk7jL): https://pastebin.com/pF8wk7jL

I'm trying to run `togglePopover` on this handler: `hotKey.keyDownHandler`.
This:

```
hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
    self.togglePopover(_:)
}
```

returns the error "Expression resolves to an unused function"
and this:

```
hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
    let call = self.togglePopover(_:)
    call(_:)
}
```

returns the error "Cannot find call in scope".
Cannot fix the issue, can someone help?
If I do:

```
hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
    print("teste")
}
```

works good!

Comment: Did you mean `hotKey.keyDownHandler = self.togglePopover(_:)`?

Comment: you should try this ```hotKey.keyDownHandler = {
            self.togglePopover(nil)
        }```

Comment: Thanks, @RajaKishan. That fixed the issue. What was the problem ended?. sweeper yes but with that I got "type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: self.togglePopover required an optional parameter so I just pass nil as a parameter.